# Mutually exclusive execution using std::atomic?

Tags: c++, atomic

I am currently learning more about lock free programming and wondered how I could implement mutual exclusion using `std::atomic`s. I implemented the following code to realize a pipe class for passing values between threads. `pipe_t` uses the `exclusive_executor_t`  to provide mutual exclusion for its critical sections. `exclusive_executor_t`  uses a `std::atomic<bool> flag` and compare and swap to prevent access to the critical section.

Unfortunately, I am not sure this implementation is correct. On my system the expected sum is correct, but of course that doesn't mean much. I am currently looking into formal methods for verifying it (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/inspector.html#gs.rlur9y), but I thought maybe the community could offer advice and guidance before I go to far down that rabbit hole. So, is it possible to implement mutual exclusion using `std::atomics` and is this implementation successfully accomplishing it?

````
#include <atomic>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename value_t>
class pipe_t {
    std::atomic<bool> is_empty{true};
    std::queue<value_t> q;

    class exclusive_executor_t {
        using flag_t = std::atomic<bool>;
        flag_t flag;

        /**
         * @breif locks this->flag
         * @note blocks until this->flag is false
         */
        void lock() {
            bool expected{false};
            while (!flag.compare_exchange_weak(expected, true,
                                               std::memory_order_acquire,
                                               std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                expected = false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * @breif releases this->flag
         * @note blocks until this->flag is true
         */
        void release() {
            bool expected{true};
            while (!flag.compare_exchange_weak(expected, false,
                                               std::memory_order_release,
                                               std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                expected = true;
            }
        }

       public:
        template <typename func_t>
        void exec(func_t fun) {
            static_assert(std::is_nothrow_invocable<func_t>::value);
            lock();
            fun();
            release();
        }
    };

    exclusive_executor_t executor;

   public:
    bool empty() const { return is_empty.load(); }

    value_t read() {
        is_empty.wait(true);
        value_t ret;
        executor.exec([&]() noexcept {
            ret = q.front();
            q.pop();
            is_empty.store(q.empty());
        });
        return ret;
    }

    void write(value_t const val) {
        executor.exec([&]() noexcept {
            q.emplace(val);
            is_empty.store(false);
        });
    }
};

long long n{1'000'000};

void f(std::shared_ptr<pipe_t<int>> p) {
    p->write(n);
    for (int i{1}; i <= n; ++i) {
        p->write(i);
    }
}

void g(std::shared_ptr<pipe_t<int>> p) {
    long long sum{0};
    int count{p->read()};
    for (int i{1}; i <= count; ++i) {
        sum += p->read();
    }
    long long const expected_sum{(n * (n + 1)) / 2};
    if (sum == expected_sum) {
        std::cout << "pass :  ";
    } else {
        std::cout << " fail : ";
    }
    std::cout << sum << " =?= " << expected_sum << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<pipe_t<int>> p{std::make_shared<pipe_t<int>>()};
    std::thread t1(f, p);
    std::thread t2(g, p);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}

```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Race condition in the `read()` method

The `read()` function waits for the queue to be nonempty with `is_empty.wait(true);`.  Then it takes the lock and retrieves `q.front()`.  However, it is possible that in between the queue becoming nonempty, and the lock being taken, some other thread takes the lock and empties the queue.  So when your original thread gets the lock, it will call `q.front()` on an empty queue, causing undefined behavior.

At the least, you need to recheck `is_empty` or `q.empty()` after taking the lock.  If it is empty, release the lock and wait again.

#### `release()` shouldn't have a loop

Your `release()` method spins until `this->flag` is true.  That might seem reasonable by symmetry with what `lock()` does, but it's not correct.

A thread must only release a lock that it currently holds (i.e. that it previously locked and has not released since then); lock and unlock calls must strictly alternate within each thread.  If `release()` is called with `this->flag == false`, this invariant has been violated, and your code has a bug somewhere.  Reasonable ways to handle this are:

- Abort the program, as this is effectively a failed assert
- Log a warning and return from `release()` without doing anything to the flag
- Don't check at all - assume that the rest of your program will always call this function correctly, i.e. with the lock held, and have `release()` simply do an unconditional `flag.store(false, std::memory_order_release);` with no compare-exchange or looping.  This is not very good defensive programming, but it does shave off a few clock cycles; and it's in the spirit of `std::mutex`, for which an attempt to unlock a mutex that isn't owned simply causes undefined behavior.  But it means that if your thread A releases a lock it doesn't hold, at a time when some other thread B actually does hold it and is in a critical section, then a third thread C could take the lock and also enter the critical section, violating mutual exclusion.

As it stands, what would happen is that the buggy thread (A) would spin in its loop, consuming CPU and energy as it goes, until some other thread (B) calls `lock()`.  Then A will exit its loop and store `false` to the flag.  This violates mutual exclusion as mentioned above. Or, maybe no other thread ever needs to lock the resource, in which case A will simply spin forever.

If you choose to go to the trouble of testing the state of the lock on entry to `release()`, then you should handle what you observe in a sensible fashion.

#### Don't confuse "blocking" with "spinning"

"Blocking" usually means having the operating system put your thread to sleep, in such a way that it will be promptly reawakened when whatever you are waiting for happens.  Like "blocking I/O".  What you are doing is *polling* in that you just test and retest the lock until you discover it is available.  Moreover you do this in a busy-loop, without any useful work or yield taking place in the meantime, so this is a *spinlock*.

The immediate implication for your code is that the `@note` comments on `lock()` and `release()` are misleading.  But more broadly, although spinlocks do correctly achieve mutual exclusion, they are problematic in other ways and are usually best avoided.  Wasting CPU cycles is one thing, but you might think it's not such a big deal if threads will only hold the lock for very short periods (a handful of instructions, say tens of nanoseconds).  The problem is that, on a non-realtime operating system, a thread holding the lock might get scheduled out, and then the lock may stay held for several *milliseconds*, which is roughly eternity on this scale.  In the meantime, *every* other thread that attempts to take the lock will be spinning, and your CPU load becomes very high.  Which in turn makes it take longer before the owning thread can be scheduled back in, so it's a vicious cycle.

So you really do want to yield the CPU back to the OS if you need to wait for the lock.  One compromise approach is that you spin for a bounded number of iterations, for the common case when the lock will be available soon, but if you don't take it within that time, you then `std::this_thread::yield()` or similar before trying again.

This is still not ideal because your thread will have to keep waking up to test the lock.  Implementations of `std::mutex` usually get assistance from the kernel, which keeps a "wait list" of threads currently blocked on this mutex.  When the owning thread unlocks it, it notifies the kernel, which selects exactly one thread from the wait list and wakes it up, while the others remain asleep.  This way there is no polling at all.  Unfortunately, you cannot duplicate this in portable C++, because the standard does not expose those kernel features other than through `std::mutex`; you'd have to write OS-specific code.

Spinlocks are mostly useful in bare-metal, kernel, or realtime code, where you can ensure that your thread won't be scheduled out because you control the scheduler, or because you have not implemented scheduling or preemption at all.  If you are already running under a proper OS then you normally would not use them.

#### Prefer `std::atomic_flag`

The `std::atomic_flag` class has more useful methods than `std::atomic<bool>` does, most notably `test_and_set` (mentioned by Davislor) which is likely to be more efficient, and more readable, than the compare-exchange loop in `lock()`.

Alternatively, if you use an integer type such as `std::atomic<unsigned char>`, you can use `fetch_or` to get this effect.  Unfortunately the standard does not include these methods for `std::atomic<bool>`.

In general, be familiar with the full stable of atomic read-modify-write operations at your disposal, including compound assignment operators which are atomic for `std::atomic` types (though they don't let you choose anything but the strongest `std::memory_order_seq_cst` ordering).  Use a compare-exchange loop only when you need to do something more complex.

#### The mutual exclusion is done correctly

Your use of acquire-release ordering in the `lock()` and `release()` methods is correct, and properly achieves the desired mutual exclusion, so your code is free of data races as far as I can see.  (The race condition mentioned in the first paragraph is a bug, but is not a *data race* in the sense of involving unsynchronized concurrent access to non-atomic objects.)

The load which verifies that the lock was available is acquire, as it must be, and it is done atomically with the store that makes the lock unavailable to other threads.  (The store side of this read-modify-write does not need stronger ordering in this case.)  The store which releases the lock is release as it must be.  Thus a release of the lock by thread A synchronizes with the load when thread B locks it, ensuring that the end of A's critical section *happens-before* the beginning of B's, in terms of the formal happens-before ordering.  This is the simplest and most classical use of acquire-release ordering.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such an insightful response. Your comments on the race condition and spin lock interaction when de scheduled are outstanding.

Comment: Agreed. Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

#### Use the Right Atomic Lock

For mutual exclusion on a resource, you normally would use a mutex lock.  That’s what it’s for, and it’ll work better than reinventing the wheel.

If reader threads should not block other reader threads, but writer threads should block other threads, you want a reader-writer lock.

If you want an atomic flag for some other purpose, that should be a [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag), rather than `std::atomic<bool>`.

#### Spin-Lock (Or Mutex Lock) Instead of Busy-Waiting

Currently, when an atomic CAS fails, you set `expected = false;` and immediately retry.  When a thread is blocked, it should pause or yield the CPU so that other threads can make progress.  The CAS loop on `flag` currently is a busy-wait that will waste CPU cycles.

You’d normally lock a mutex by creating a `std::mutex` object and calling `.lock()` on it, which puts the thread to sleep until the mutex is unlocked.  If you’re going to roll your own spinlock, a simple one would look something like this:

```cpp
  while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }
```

If the threads need to see each other’s updates to the data, they should use acquire/release memory ordering.  In practice, you’d use a mutex lock for this, or maybe something like a test-and-test-and-set pattern in cases of high contention.

#### Use Lock-Free Algorithms if Appropriate

You can often use a pattern such as receive-copy-update with a CAS loop on an object small enough to be updated with a single CAS instruction, or a data structure that supports lock-free insertion (such as a singly-linked list with CAS on the head or tail pointer).

In this case, if you have a single writer and multiple readers, you might use a producer-consumer model for your pipe.

In the test driver, you’re taking a sum.  This is probably just an arbitrary test of the pipe, but if you actually wanted to do that, you could use `atomic_fetch_add` on the atomic counter.  Or if the purpose of a pipe is to transfer data from one thread to one or more other threads, you might atomically move a `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T[]>>>` to the underlying array.

However, mutex locks have low overhead and will usually perform well.

#### You Don’t Need Shared Pointers

Either you’re treating the entire object as an atomic object with the RCU pattern, or it’s safe to call members without any additional synchronization, because the object handles that itself using atomic data members.

If the object itself should only be accessed atomically, you want each thread to hold a `std::atomic<T>&` or a `std::atomic_ref<T>` to the same object, whose lifetime should expire when all the threads join.  If all you need to do is have an atomic read or write, this takes care of it for you.  You don’t need the overhead of reference counting.

If the object does its own synchronization, using its internal atomic data members, you can just give every thread a reference to it.  Note that this is not safely portable if the threads can both read and write the data members through the reference—you are supposed to guarantee that no thread reads from the same object while another is writing to it!  If you do this, make the data `private:` and provide safe getters and updaters.

Comment: To elaborate, `std::mutex` is also just using a single atomic operation to lock and unlock itself in the uncontended case. The difference is when you try to lock a `std::mutex` that is already locked; instead of trying the atomic operation again in a tight loop, it calls the kernel and tells it "please let me sleep until someone else modifies this atomic variable I am interested in". Spinning like you do in `exclusive_executor_t` is only better if you expect a lot of contention *and* you know that you will only hold the lock for a very short time.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Good point. Cleaned that explanation up.